# Open ScrollView by Click

Tags: android, scrollview

I want to open a horizontal ScrollView with images by clicking on a central image. I already have my ScrollView loading dynamically my images:

```
int[] images = new int[] { R.drawable.image1, R.drawable.image2, R.drawable.image3 };
LinearLayout sv;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_advanced);

    sv = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ScrollView);

    for (int i = 0; i<images.length; i++) {
        ImageView iv = new ImageView(this);
        iv.setBackgroundResource(images[i]);
        sv.addView(iv);
    }
}
```

I have following problem, right now the ScrollView is already expand, but I want the ScrollView to expand when clicking on the last selected image from the ScrollView (and a default one if its the first time). I dont know if ScrollView is the right way to do that or if there is a better method for that. I already searched on Stackoverflow and found similiar questions but no of them did really fit my problem.

Hope someone can help me
If this question is already answered somewhere and I didnt found it, send me the link please.

Thanks in advance